# I can't run any version of swagger-fox. Spring Boot 2.4.2 + JDK 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

This is the first time I can't get any version of swagger-fox up and running. Spring Boot 2.4.2 + JDK 8. I have previously added swagger-fox to my projects using the instruction below, but none fit.

Link on tutorial - https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Failed Run  - https://pastebin.com/G34kGMc3

**P.S. Sorry, I went crazy and took the file from the wrong branch. I've updated the file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parser</name>
    <description>The parser for my format.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                        <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I couldn't see the `springfox` dependency in your `pom.xml` file. I understand from [your example](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api#dependency) that this should be added.

Comment: Sorry, I went crazy and took the file from the wrong branch.

Comment: I updated the file.

Comment: I got a succesfull run using recommended versions by  the `springfox-boot-starter` instead of 2.9.2, you my try removing `springfox-swagger2` & `springfox-swagger-ui` dependencies from your pom.xml

Comment: Great advice, it helped. Thank you!

Comment: @eHayik might want to add that as answer. HtmlMan: in general you shouldn't specify versions yourself when using spring parents, always default to given versions. you have lot of extra explicitness in your pom.

Answer (score 4):

You should use recommended versions by the `springfox-boot-starter` as @eis has mentioned in comments you shouldn't override specified versions by spring boot starters unless you have an issue with recommended versions.

Removing version tag from `springfox-swagger2` & `springfox-swagger-ui` dependencies from your `pom.xml` will fix the issue.

I also has configured swagger using the same tutorial several times, I noticed that `springfox-boot-starter` has been added recently. You don't need to delcare `springfox-swagger2`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: And also for correcting mistakes in the text!

Comment: you need just import springfox-boot-starter because it contains  already  springfox-swagger-ui ;)